# How to disable one toggler when another toggler is not toggle back yet?

Tags: javascript

I have a image with 2 buttons:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div>
        <a class="a-button>Toggle A</a>
        <a class="b-button>Toggle B</a>
    </div>
    <p id="statics">Statics numbers</p>
   <p id='chart">Chart</p>
</div>
<div class="item-img"><img src="..."></div>
```

If I want to view #statics, I click a-button to hide item-img. Then, click again to show img and hide #statics.

If I want to view #chart, I click b-button to hide item-img, then, click again to show item-img and hide #chart.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $(".a-button").click(function () {
        $("#statics").toggle("slow");
        $(".item-img").toggle('slow');
        });
    $(".b-button").click(function () {
        $("#chart").toggle("slow");
        $(".item-img").toggle('slow');
        });
});
```

The problem is-- If I hide item-img by either toggler a-button or b-button, Then, click the other toggler(a or b) before click the first toggler to show the item -img again, Both #statics and #chart show up, make a big mess.

How can I disable one toggler when another toggler is not toggle back yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $(".a-button").click(function () {
        if(!$("#chart").is(':visible')) {
            $("#statics").toggle("slow");
            $(".item-img").toggle('slow');
        }
        });
    $(".b-button").click(function () {
        if(!$("#statics").is(':visible')) {
            $("#chart").toggle("slow");
            $(".item-img").toggle('slow');
        }
        });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2q3k/)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var state;

    $(".a-button").click(function () {
        $("#statics").toggle("slow");
        $(".item-img").toggle('slow');

        state = $(".b-button").prop('disabled');
        $(".b-button").prop('disabled', !state);
    });
    $(".b-button").click(function () {
        $("#chart").toggle("slow");
        $(".item-img").toggle('slow');

        state = $(".a-button").prop('disabled');
        $(".a-button").prop('disabled', !state);
    });
});
```

**Edit**: Didn't realize you weren't using actual buttons, [see working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yfruG/) with this updated html (not sure if you have the option to change those):

```
<input type="button" class="a-button" value="Toggle A">
<input type="button" class="b-button" value="Toggle B">
```